# How to execute python file from php to update mysql table?

Tags: php, python, mysql

I'm trying to do a button click that run a python file to do naive bayes and update the values to Mysql table. My code as below:

**Controller.php**

```
public function execute_excel()
{
    shell_exec('python D:\laravel-crud\public\admin\mysqlku.py');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**mysqlku.py**

```
*some codes*
# update the database with new values
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
for key,row in values.iterrows():
    up = conn.execute("UPDATE mahasiswa SET daftar_kembali = '{}' WHERE id_mahasiswa = {}"
                       .format(row['daftar_kembali'], row['id_mahasiswa']))
    logging.debug(up)
```

I can update the mysql table perfectly fine when I directly run the `mysqlku.py` with Spyder/Terminal, but can't do so in `Controller.php`.

Anyone know how to make it work with `shell_exec()`?

The ResultProxy debugging doesn't show up in Spyder but it shows in Terminal.

```
DEBUG:root:<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x000001DE4671C5C0>
DEBUG:root:<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x000001DE4671C668>
DEBUG:root:<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x000001DE4671C5F8>
etc.
```

Comment: You are executing the PHP script via a webpage? Because then it will most likely run under the user `www-data` which normally does not have the rights to execute e.g. Python.

Comment: @Tox any way to handle it? I'm still new to web programming

Comment: Yes, you can add `www-data` to the `sudoers` **but** that is not advisable as it's a potentially huge security issue. What you can try is to change the owner of the Python script: `chown www-data:www-data /path/to/my/script.py`.

Comment: @Tox sorry I couldn't do your advice due to me using Windows OS (chown is not recognized as an internal or external command), I was trying to solve it using takeown /f mysqlku.py but no result so far. Do you know anyway to do it for Windows?

Comment: It's been a while since I developed on Windows, so I'm not sure what limitations apply there. Doing a right-click on the file and then choosing `properties` you can view the `security` settings of a file that determine who is allowed which kind of access. As to which user you need to give the rights others will have to advise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to interact with the ResultProxy. As per SQLAlchemy's [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/connections.html):

The returned result is an instance of ResultProxy, which references a DBAPI cursor and provides a largely compatible interface with that of the DBAPI cursor. The DBAPI cursor will be closed by the ResultProxy when all of its result rows (if any) are exhausted. **A ResultProxy that returns no rows, such as that of an UPDATE statement (without any returned rows),** releases cursor resources immediately upon construction.

Try this:

```
logging.debug(up.fetchall())
```

Reference site : https://code-maven.com/slides/python-programming/sqlalchemy-engine-select

Comment: I got this error: ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

Comment: Okay, as i said update query never rerturns data, can you please check with select query, also did the data updates when this program executes ??

Comment: It works with select query (to debug it, but can't show it to the web). Yes, the data updates when the program executed directly from python, but can't do it with shell_exec() in php

Comment: That's it, query is being executed but as i said update query never returns data..

Comment: so if you find and object of ResulyProxy that assume that data is updated

Comment: It did show ResultProxy in Terminal, but it didn't show neither ResultProxy nor error object in the web (blank page). I think it has something to do with Apache user www-data like Tox said, but I couldn't do his advice due to me using Windows OS, I was trying to solve it using takeown /f mysqlku.py but no result so far. Do you know anyway to do it for Windows?